animated film similar to Joseph:King of Dreams, but older
I remember an animated film from my childhood about the biblical Joseph.
It is not Joseph: King of Dreams by Dreamworks since it is too new. The storyline seems to be more or less exactly the same as the Dreamworks one though. No wonder, since both have the same biblical source. The version in question I search is at most from the 90's, but may also be from the 80's.
The scene where Joseph interprets the Pharaoh's dreams especially looks different in my head. No CGI, fully hand-drawn. Real corn being eaten by deathly corn, not some stone with a corn symbol like in Dreamwork's version.
When Potiphar's wife tries to seduce Joseph, I remember her singing a song "Joseph, ach Joseph, was bist du so keusch" (I watched in Germany, so in German). I hope this is a real memory and not mixing memories together with Madame Pompadour.
If I remember correctly, in the scene right after where Joseph is sold, he walks with his hands bound to a camel towards his destiny, falling down repeatedly.

You are looking for:
Joseph and the Coat of Many Colors (1999)

You can find the full movie, split into parts, on Youtube:




It sounds similar to Joseph and His Brothers - Hanna Barbera the Greatest Adventure Stories From the Bible (1990)
IMDB



Movie

Thank you, but this is still the wrong movie. It was completely contained inside the biblical time, not with an archaeologist story (like your guess) as an outer wrapper.
